# how to use wget spider to identify broken urls from a list of urls and save broken ones

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I am trying to write a shell script to identify broken urls from a list of urls.

here is input_url.csv sample:

```
https://www.google.com/
https://www.nbc.com
https://www.google.com.hksjkhkh/
https://www.google.co.jp/
https://www.google.ca/
```

Here is what I have which works:

```
    wget --spider -nd -nv -H --max-redirect 0 -o run.log -i input_url.csv
```

and this gives me '2019-09-03 19:48:37 URL: https://www.nbc.com 200 OK' for valid urls, and for broken ones it gives me '0 redirections exceeded.'

what i expect is that i only want to save those broken links into my output file.

sample expect output:

```
https://www.google.com.hksjkhkh/
```

Comment: and my input_url file is large, so i should have a script that could run efficiently.

Comment: Can you post example part of input file (like 5 lines) and example part of output (like 5 lines). Wouldn't it be better to run `wget` for each link in parallel?

Comment: sure, let me post an example.

Comment: posted a sample url file.  and how can I run `wget` in parallel? @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would go with:

```
<input.csv xargs -n1 -P10 sh -c 'wget --spider --quiet "$1" || echo "$1"' --
```

You can use `-P <count>` option to `xargs` to run `count` processes in parallel.

`xargs` runs the command `sh -c '....' --` for each line of the input file appending the input file line as the argument to the script.

Then `sh` inside runs `wget ... "$1"`. The `||` checks if the return status is nonzero, which means failure. On `wget` failure, `echo "$1"` is executed.

[Live code link at repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LinedGreedyTransformation).

You could filter the output of `wget -nd -nv` and then regex the output, well like

```
wget --spider -nd -nv -H --max-redirect 0 -i input 2>&1 | grep -v '200 OK' | grep 'unable' | sed 's/.* .//; s/.$//'
```

but this looks not expendable, is not parallel so probably is slower and probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: sorry, i am not proficient in shell, why we have `<` in front?, could you please give me a specified sample command? thank you!

Comment: This is a specified sample command. You can copy the line and use it. The `<` redirects file to the command stdin. It's the same as `cat input.csv | xargs ....`. The `< file` can be anywhere in the command, so you can `< input.csv xargs echo`  or `xargs <input.csv echo`. [some reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) I added code link to repl if you want to test it out. I like to put input redirection up front, but if you like it better do `xargs -l -P10 ..... < input.csv`

Comment: why do i got this error? `xargs: illegal option -- l` @KamilCuk

Comment: Are you on some strange linux? MacOS? HP/UX? etc.?

Comment: i am on MacOS @KamilCuk

Comment: So you have [macos xargs](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html) and not [linux xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and they differ. You can install the original xargs. Or I think you can just replace `-l` with `-n1` or `-L1` and it should be safe. There shouldn't be any spaces or tabs in urls. It would be better if you next time tag the question with the target operating system ; )